# How to set zoom slider value to a particular point when map loads in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, arcgis

I have a flex application which shows ArcGis Map .Currently the map shows 20 Zoom levels.Is it possible to Load map with the given zoom level,Say level 10.so that when the map loads the zoom slider moves to level 10.

Zoom Slider Code.

```
<s:HSlider id="alphaSlider" visible="{map.layers.length &gt; 0}"
                               liveDragging="true" maximum="1.8" minimum="0" showDataTip="false"
                               snapInterval=".1" stepSize=".1" styleName="horizontalSlider" value="0.9"/>
```

Zoom Levels.

```
<esri:lods>
<esri:LOD level="0" resolution="156543.03392800014" scale="5.91657527591555E8"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="1" resolution="78271.51696399994" scale="2.95828763795777E8"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="2" resolution="39135.75848200009" scale="1.47914381897889E8"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="3" resolution="19567.87924099992" scale="7.3957190948944E7"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="4" resolution="9783.93962049996" scale="3.6978595474472E7"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="5" resolution="4891.96981024998" scale="1.8489297737236E7"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="6" resolution="2445.98490512499" scale="9244648.868618"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="7" resolution="1222.992452562495" scale="4622324.434309"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="8" resolution="611.4962262813797" scale="2311162.217155"/>
                        <esri:LOD level="9" resolution="305.74811314055756" scale="1155581.108577"/>
....
...

..
..

                        <esri:LOD level="19" resolution="152.87405657041106" scale="577790.554289"/>

</esri:lods>
```

Any Help is Appretiated..

Comment: This looks like a question better suited to [**GIS Stack Exchange**](http://gis.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map has a "level" property that you can set.

I'm not sure if this is already taken into account when initially loading the map however. If not, you can listen for the "load" event on the map and set the level when the map is loaded.

Also, wouldn't it be more convenient to use a range from 0 to 19 (the number of levels - 1) and a stepSize of 1 on you slider? That way you could bind the value to the level property of the map.

```
<s:HSlider id="alphaSlider" visible="{map.layers.length &gt; 0}" liveDragging="true" maximum="19" minimum="0" showDataTip="false" snapInterval="1" stepSize="1" styleName="horizontalSlider" value="{parseInt(map.level)}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.What will "map.level" return.from where i am getting that value.

Comment: According to the docs, this returns the ID of the level of detail: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/Map.html